# How can get the count or the number of div class in the mentioed screenshot in Selenium with java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webautomation

[image]

I want to extract the marked div count in selenium and java.

Comment: tried with                                                                                                                        List<WebElement> TotalRowsList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#tbodyid"));
        System.out.println("number of phone is-1 " + TotalRowsList.size());
Or
        int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tbodyid\"]")).size();
        System.out.println("number of phone is " + rowCount);

Answer (score 0):

You are working with the parent div while asking about its children.

Try the following:
CSS:

> driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#tbodyid > div"))

xPath:

> driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='tbodyid']/div"))